# Google wallet annual recurring subscriptions?

Tags: android-pay

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/subscriptions) Google Wallet seems to only support monthly recurring subscriptions.

I'd to charge users annually for the use of an application hosted on AppEngine (purely to be able to offer the user a better price and reduce administrative costs). Are there any plans to support annually recurring subscriptions?

Or is there a way to configure the current subscription system to behave as an annual subscription system?

Comment: Divide the annual subscription amount by 12?

Comment: Of course! But the point is to avoid running 12 transactions a year. Also rewarding the customer with a better price only works if they pay upfront for all 12 months.

Comment: Does Wallet allow for refunds?  Maybe you could give customers a partial refund after 12 months, equal to the discount amount.  That would reward them for being loyal customers.  I am interested in Wallet as well and would like to know what options you find.

Comment: Sounds like a hack. My aim is to reduce administrative efforts/costs.

Comment: Based on your stated goal, until Google does, can't you handle it yourself? Your own scheduler - re: nothing to do with Google's subscription feature (to Google its **not** a subscription, but **it is to you**).

Comment: @EdSF That is my fallback plan. Thought it was worth asking if there was an official solution.

Comment: Got it - only a Googler can give you info on future plans....

Comment: @EdSF I was hoping a Googler noticed this post since it's their preferred way of collaborating of Wallet

Answer (score 0):

Technically there's no way to configure an annual subscription. But I suppose you can work around it: Request an initial payment for the entire first year and then a monthly-recurring payment at a discount.

For example, suppose you offer a monthly plan that costs $100. And you want to offer an annual plan for $900 (25% discount). Instead, you may offer an initial payment of $900 followed by 36 monthly-recurring payments of $75.

What this means for your business is that once a user has paid for and used your service for an entire year then you start treating her as a "loyal customer" and let her keep paying the discount price without committing for another year.

Answer (score 0):

Wallet for Digital Goods currently only supports a monthly frequency for subscriptions.
https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#jwt

there is no official solution for an annual subscription, but you could implement a solution similar to what @oferei or @EdSF suggested in their posts.